# grep to format two numbers with ','

Tags: linux, grep

```
sensors|grep -oP "Core 1:\s*\+\K[0-9]+" >> lmsenreading1.txt
```

Then:

```
sensors|grep -oP "Core 0:\s*\+\K[0-9]+" >> lmsenreading0.txt
```

Then join the two `.txt` files with a delimiter `,`.
This should give, for example, `65,66`

If I use

```
sensors|grep -oP ":\s*\+\K[0-9]+"
```

my output is

```
27

65

66
```

The `27` is not required.

How do I format the output from `sensors|grep -oP ":\s*\+\K[0-9]+"` 
to give:

```
65,66
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grep for "Core ." which matches Core 0 and Core 1 (on my system 0 and 2):

```
sensors | grep -oP "Core .:\s*\+\K[0-9]+" | tr "\n" "," 
46,42,
```

and use tr(anslate) to change newlines to commas.

This serves you with an additional comma in the end.

You get rid of it with substringing from start (0) to one before the end (-1):

```
sens=$(sensors | grep -oP "Core .:\s*\+\K[0-9]+" | tr "\n" ",")
echo ${sens: 0: -1}
47,44
```

Comment: you can also use `paste -sd,` to combine multiple lines into one...

Comment: @vigilancewx: The canonical way to thank is not by comment, but by hitting the fancy `^v`-Symbols on the left and/or the check mark. If you hover over it with the mouse, a tooltip tells you, when to use which. I guess you find more infos about it in the tour. The check mark can be spend only on one answer, but might be put elsewhere, if an even better answer arrives.

Answer (score 0):

No need for files or variables, just use `printf` and *command substitution*:

```
printf '%s,%s\n' $(sensors | grep -oP 'Core [01]:\s*\+\K[0-9]+')
```

Output on my system:

```
53,54
```

Note the change to the `grep` *regex*: instead of individual chars of *0* and *1* to specify core numbers, a character class `[01]` checks both cores.